# Why does LMDB perform better on keys which already have previous data?

Tags: c, database, performance, database-performance, lmdb

I've been working on a system using LMDB and I've stumbled across some weird characteristics that I don't understand, so I'm hoping you can help me.

I've found that if I were to have some data; any data; even smaller sized data; previously written as key's value initially, the database will be faster and have less variance to its write performance than if I were to just write a new key and value at the same time.

This doesn't make to much sense to me at the moment. I would have thought if the key initialised with data that isn't of the same size there would be no effect. Even if there were some advantage to having space reserved for the real value for the key, it wouldn't be enough. Apparently not though.

Is there any reason why this might be the case? Is there also any other databases which exhibit this type of behaviour?

Thank you in advance of your help,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I were to have some data; any data; even smaller sized data; previously written as key's value initially, the database will be faster and have less variance to its write performance

There are many, many factors that affect perceived database performance.   But, to focus on the effect you're observing, consider how LMDB manages its store.  You could look at the code, of course, but oftentimes in database implementations, it helps just to consider what you would do if you were confronted with the implementor's problem.

You seem to be assuming that every LMDB record is exactly as big as the sum of its key & data sizes.  If that were so, then smaller sized existing data would force LMDB to allocate a new ... *something* to hold a larger-sized updated value.  And LMDB would have to manage its storage according to the exact size of each record.

To avoid those problems, ISTR LDMB uses a few memory "bins" of fixed sizes.  A new record gets its allocation from the bin whose size accommodates the data.  Perhaps your tests happen to be of similar enough size to fit in the same bin, so all you're doing is overwriting the same storage.

Comment: I think you are right, I didn't consider that binning data would be a factor. I noticed that if I change the size dramatically this effect disappears. Following from this do you think that if you know what size of data would be filled in as a key's value, would it be a good practice to prewrite some dummy data to the value?

Comment: If you're asking me, no.  I would do everything else first.  I would write the application, get it to do what it's supposed to do, and put it in users' hands.  When testing shows the biggest problem in the whole system is that it's slow in this one particular way, then I'd change the 18 lines that "preallocate" the record.  My guess is that day will never arrive.

Comment: I don't believe LMDB can ever overwrite the same storage, since keeping the old copy around is required for MVCC. If I had to guess, I'd say the performance difference has to do with the page cache, and the number of page faults required.